# STM32 UART Only transmits few bytes then stops

Tags: c, serial-port, embedded, stm32, uart

I'm writing a program that sends serial data from STM32F429 Dev Board to PC via UART. The program sends a message but each time stops when it should keep sending the data at the same amount of bytes (157).

The data I receive through a terminal program on my PC is correct but the terminal only shows 157 bytes received doesn't matter what input I give. 
The board still runs and the while loop keeps executing (checked with a counter watch in debug) but no new data is received on port after 157 bytes.

```
int main(void)
{
    HAL_Init();
    SystemClock_Config();
    MX_USART1_UART_Init();
    __HAL_UART_ENABLE_IT(&huart1, UART_IT_TC);

    /* Infinite loop */
    while (1)
    {
       if(serialFlag)
       {
           char Message[13];
           for(int i=1;i<6;i++)
           {
               SendMessage("Hello\n\r");
               HAL_Delay(1);
           }

           serialFlag=false;
       }
    }
}
```

My ISR after transmision of my UART

```
void HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
    __HAL_UART_FLUSH_DRREGISTER(&huart1);
}
```

Initialisation:

```
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void)
{
     huart1.Instance = USART1;
     huart1.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
     huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
     huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
     huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
     huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
     huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
     huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
     if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
     {
        Error_Handler();
     }
}
```

This procedure handles the text sent to the UART

```
void SendMessage(char str[]) 
{
    char *result = (char *)malloc(strlen(str)+1);
    strcpy(result,str);
    HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart1,(uint8_t*)result, strlen(str));
}
```

Comment: Do you have a memory leak in `SendMessage`? You `malloc` memory but do not appear to `free` it. But why do you do that anyway?

Comment: Using `malloc` & co is definitively the wrong approach on that platform. Embedded software is not the same as PC software.

Comment: Thank you Olaf and Weather Vane. Yes That was the problem. Wasn't thinking when implementing the malloc. Caused memory leak.

Comment: @JacoBester Post your fixed code as an answer and include in the answer what have you learnt. Just to share the useful information with the community.